# nsIDOMWindowUtils.isInModalState() not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I get the `utils` of the window like this:

```
var utils = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').
            QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
            getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
```

then running this code says its not a function:

```
Services.prompt.alert(null, 'is modal?', utils.isInModalState())
//Exception: utils.isInModalState is not a function
```

even though it says [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#isInModalState%28%29) it is.

I am not able to run this code either:

```
utils.enterModalState()
```

It runs without error but the window does not enter or leave modal state.

Comment: About "It runs without error but the window does not enter or leave modal state." What makes you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: When I click on the window things are still accessible. You know when you use `Services.prompt.alert(null, 'blah', 'blah')` the window in the back can't be clicked, or minimized. I thought Modal is supposed to be like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.isInModalState` property is actually [tagged `[noscript]`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/f93c0ef45597/dom/interfaces/base/nsIDOMWindowUtils.idl#l55), so it is not available in Javascript, only C++.

`.enterModalState()` doesn't do what you think it does. It does not make a window UI-modal (like an alert dialog). It just essentially suspends scripts and event processing in the window.

Comment: Thanks. On MDN they didn't state that it's no script. :( Do you know how to deactivate window like that? I'm looking to also re-enable once a window is in it.