# Block script execution in Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon

Probably looking for an answer to an age-old question, but I would like to block script execution.  In my use-case blocking the browser is acceptable.

Also, in my use-case I am trying to do this from a Firefox extension, which means my code is "Chrome code", running in the browser environment.

This can easily be done by using a modal window, then programmatically closing the window.  So this demonstrates that there is a blocking mechanism that exists.

Is there any way to achieve modal blocking without actually creating or opening the modal window?  Some way to tap into the blocking mechanism used for modal windows?

I've done a lot of searching on this subject, but to no avail.

Comment: Didn't mention that I want to do this in Firefox extension run in browser context. Does that open up a possiblity? (updated OP and title to reflect this)

Comment: Yes, that definitely will change the question totally ; ).

Answer (score 1):

Using nsIProcess you can block the thread.

You can create an executable which has a sleep or usleep method or equivalent.  Then run the process synchronously (nsIProcess.run) and set blocking argument to true.

Of course for portability you will need to create an executable appropriate for each platform you wish to support, and supply code for discrimination.

Basic code is something like the following.  I have verified on 'nix (Mac OS X) this code to work, using a bash script with only the line `sleep .03`:

```
let testex = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

testex.initWithPath("/Users/allasso/Desktop/pause.sh");

let process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

process.init(testex);
let delay = 30;  // convert this to milliseconds in the executable
process.run(true,[delay],1);  // `run` method runs synchronously, first arg says to block thread
```

In an extension you probably would want to make your nsIFile file object more portable:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
let testex = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD",["extension@moz.org","resources","pause.sh"]);
```

Of course keep in mind that Javascript is basically single-threaded, so unless you are blocking a thread spawned using Web Workers you will be freezing the entire UI during the sleep period (just like you would if you opened a modal window).

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProcess

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFile

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Getting_special_files

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION 1

There is `enterModalState` and `leaveModalState` in `nsIDOMWindowUtils` here: [MDN :: nsIDOMWindowUtils Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils#enterModalState%28%29)

However they don't seem to work for me. This topic might explain why: [nsIDOMWindowUtils.isInModalState() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684696/nsidomwindowutils-isinmodalstate-not-working/24684793#24684793) they topic says `isInModalState` is marked `[noscript]` which I see, but `enterModalState` and `leaveModalState` are not marked `[noscript]` I have no idea why it's not working.

What does work for me though is `suppressEventHandling`:

```
var utils = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').
            QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
            getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

utils.suppressEventHandling(true); //set arg to false to unsupress
```

### OPTION 2

You can open a tiny window with the source window as the window you want to make modal and as dialog but open it off screen. Its dialog so it wont show a new window the OS tab bars. However hitting alt+f4 will close that win, but you can attach event listeners (or maybe use the utils.suppressEventHandling so keyboard doesnt work in it) to avoid the closing till you want it closed. Here's the code:

```
    var sDOMWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
    var sa = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-array;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsArray);
    var wuri = Cc["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
    wuri.data = 'about:blank';
    sa.AppendElement(wuri);
    let features = "chrome,modal,width=1,height=1,left=-100";
    if (PrivateBrowsingUtils.permanentPrivateBrowsing || PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate(sDOMWin)) {
       features += ",private";
    } else {
       features += ",non-private";
    }
    var XULWindow = Services.ww.openWindow(sDOMWin, 'chrome://browser/content/browser.xul', null, features, sa);
/*
    XULWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var DOMWindow = XULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
      DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.stop(Ci.nsIWebNavigation.STOP_ALL);
      DOMWindow.gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther(DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab, aTab);
      //DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
    }, false);
*/
```

Comment: suppressEventHandling only suppresses event handling.  It does not pause execution when a script is running as the op asks. The title is misleading though and suppressEventHandling could qualify for that, so perhaps I should change it.

Comment: I have tried Option 2 on OS X and am not able to display the window "off screen", as any off-screen parameters will cause the window to display on the nearest edge of the screen. Maybe calling moveTo(x,y) after opening would work, but I doubt it.  Also Firefox honors the OS's minimum window dimensions, which on OS X is 60px x 60px.  You will see it flicker even if immediately close after opening.  Maybe this behavior is different on other OSs.

Comment: Another glitch with Option 2 is the large overhead of creating, opening and closing the window which is not only causing a delay in the thread, but using system resources. And small delays will approach the time it takes to do this.  I spent a lot of time exploring this vein and it did not seem feasible which led me to post the question :-)

Comment: Seems like enter/leaveModalState should work, as you say it is does not have a [noscript] declaration, but nevertheless it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, one way to get a hidden modal is leave the url in open() blank.  I suspect there is not really a hidden window anywhere, but doing this does trigger the modal state.  This also uses much less overhead.  Unfortunately there is not a way to get a reference to the window to "close" it programmatically after a delay :-/ that I can tell.  Even trying to "close" it manually using the escape button doesn't work in this case.  Perhaps if someone explored it enough they could figure out a way to leave the modal state...

Comment: Awesome research man!! Maybe we should make another topic asking on how to get `enter/leaveModalState` working